# How to review all CSS changes on Chrome?

Tags: css, google-chrome

I have made some changes of CSS styles on the website under chrome, how can I review all changes I have made? So that I can apply all these changes to the web server.

[image: screenshot about css changes in chrome]

Comment: Use Firefox. It appends a colored bar in front of each style that has been changed or added.

Answer (score 0):

Pencil and paper :) Welcome to the club, and good luck tracking them down! We've all been there before, and we'll all be there again.

Comment: Haha I agree. Its a habit